# How can i delete selected data from grid on the button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid on my page and using check box for checking one or more than one row in grid and i want to delete checked row from grid on the click of delete button which is out side the grid..

In table i have only name field there is no field like ID.

How can i delete record.

Thanks in advance..

Here is my code What i am doing:-

```
private void GetData()
{

    ArrayList arr;
    if (ViewState["TotalRecords"] != null)
    {
        arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["TotalRecords"];
    }
    else
    {
        arr = new ArrayList();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grdlistWord.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("chkWord");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            if (!arr.Contains(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1]))
            {
                arr.Add(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr.Contains(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1]))
            {
                arr.Remove(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1]);
            }
        }

    }
    ViewState["TotalRecords"] = arr;
}

protected void lnkbtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        int count = 0;

        ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["TotalRecords"];
        count = arr.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < grdlistWord.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (arr.Contains(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text))
            {
                Response.Write(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
                DeleteRecord(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
                arr.Remove(grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
            }
        }
        ViewState["TotalRecords"] = arr;
        GridBind();

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }

}


private void DeleteRecord(string word)
{

    string query = "delete from searchword where word=@word";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

gridview html detail:

```
 <fieldset>
        <legend>List</legend>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdlistWord" runat="server" DataKeyNames="word" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="grdlistWord_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdlistWord_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWord" runat="server" onclick="check_click(this);" />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Word" HeaderText="Word" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Edit" Text="edit" DataNavigateUrlFields="Word" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SearchWord.aspx?words={0}&amp;mode=Edit" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderText="Delete" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>Records not exist!</EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCount" runat="server" Value = "0" />

    </fieldset>
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you're seeing from this code, and what are you expecting? Are you seeing any exceptions (besides that the code won't compile)?

Comment: @p.campbell: it is not getting the word to fulfill the where condition of the delete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void lnkbtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int counter = 0;
            List<string> words = new List<string>();
            foreach (GridViewRow rowitem in grdlistWord.Rows)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)rowitem.Cells[0].FindControl("chkWord")).Checked == true)//i consider that the check box is in the first column index ---> 0
                {
                    counter++;
                    words.Add(rowitem.Cells[1].Text); //i consider that the word is in the second column index ---> 1
                }
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if(counter == 0) //no checks
            {

             //show some message box to clarify that no row has been selected.

            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (counter == 1) //one check
            {

                DeleteRecord(words[0]);
                //Show some message box to clarify that the operation has been executed successfully.

            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (counter > 1) //more than one check
            {
                for(int i=0; i<words.Count;i++)
                   {
                     DeleteRecord(words[i]);
                   }
                   //Show some message box to clarify that the operation has been executed successfully.
            }

            grdlistWord.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: but on doing this i have an error i.e. The best overloaded method match for '_Default.DeleteRecord(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: According to you:private void DeleteRecord(string word),so it takes a string and the Words is a list of strings..
two notes:
1-using System.Collections.Generic;(use the previous namespace  to use List collection)..
2-please post the aspx pof the GridView part to identify precisely the index of each column , i assume it in my code.

Comment: what is the data source of your grid view?and when you bind the grid view?

Comment: please put a break point on the event handler of `lnkbtnDelete`
and tell me the `Count` of `words` and

Comment: tell me what happens when enter  DeleteRecord();

Comment: please remove this from your `aspx`::

`onclick="check_click(this);` in this line::
`<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
`

Comment: breakpoint on lnkbtnDelete_Click () is not working i think lnkbtnDelete_Click event is not fired on page..:-(

Comment: use any validation on the page??

Comment: i was using validation but there is no validation on my page.

Comment: try to put a button out side the grid view, and copy my code in it, put a break point at this button and tell me the result?

Comment: tell me when you click the link button , it makes post back or not??\

Comment: hmmm,what happened when you click the mouse on the gray column on the left hand side, it puts a red bullet or not?

Comment: put this bullet at the button click event handler and click `f5`

Comment: `((CheckBox)rowitem.Cells[0].FindControl("chkWord")).Checked == true`
is this condition is true when you put a break point or not?

Comment: please remove this from your aspx:: `onclick="check_click(this);` in this line:: `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);"`

Comment: no ((CheckBox)rowitem.Cells[0].FindControl("chkWord")).Checked == true condition is false.

Comment: you forgot to check the items u wanna to delete??
or u don't remove this `onclick="checkAll(this);"`?

Comment: hmmm , you make some thing wrong , because if you checked some items and after that click the button of delete. at some iteration in the loop :

Comment: `((CheckBox)rowitem.Cells[0].FindControl("chkWord")).Checked == true`
should be true and the counter will increase by one.

Comment: i have posted my coding in answer please go though this and check what i am doing...

Comment: According to your `aspx` the check box is in the Cells[0], and in your code behind `Cells[1]`

Comment: if u try the code i wrote as it is , it will works for u , i tried it and it works , may be you make some wrong in the grid view dat bound or still use the link button in the grid view

Comment: i used link button outside the gridview..used Cells[0] for checkbox..have you checked my code that i posted??

Comment: i think i fix your problem.
in the page load event:
`if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            grdlistWord.DataBind();

        }` instead of binding directly in the page load.

Comment: this will fix your problem for sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121297/how-can-i-email-comment-on-my-email-id/6121335#6121335

Comment: Okay i will take a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you have set a primary key id first in your table, which you are fetching as a source of the Grid.

After binding the grid you should save that id in a hidden field. see the code below:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="gvwID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataKeyNames="TableID">
           <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("TableID") %>'/>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
```

Then in the delete button click event get the selected row ids:

```
        protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                int[] OrderIDList = new int[gvwID.Rows.Count];

                int index = 0;

                 for (int count = 0; count < gvwID.Rows.Count; count++)
                 {
                   if (gvwID.Rows[count].FindControl("chkSelect") != null)
                    {
                       if (((CheckBox)gvwID.Rows[count].FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked)
                       {
                            if (gvwID.Rows[count].FindControl("HiddenField1") != null)
                            {
                            string OrderID = ((HiddenField)gvwID.Rows[count].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
                        OrderIDList[index++] = Convret.ToInt32(OrderID);
                             }
                        }
                   }
        }
```

Then create an appended string from OrderIDList and pass it to the stored procedure. from the stored procedure create an xml using the appended string. Loop through the xml and get each id and perform the deletion.

see the procedure below:

```
              @IDList varchar(MAX)

            DECLARE @xmlUserIDs xml
    SELECT @xmlUserIDs = CONVERT(xml,'<root><cat>' +  REPLACE(@IDList,',','</cat><cat>') + '</cat></root>')// creates xml from appended string

    DELETE FROM  
        [TableName]
    WHERE 
    [TableID] IN (SELECT 
                    [Value] = T.C.value('.','int') 
                  FROM 
                    @xmlUserIDs.nodes('/root/cat') T(C));
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: @Divya, The OrderIDList should be converted to a string with a seperator character (here it is a comma). This worked for me..Normally a unique id (primary key) is used to perform any update/delete operations on a particular record in db..

Comment: @Divya,check the stored procedure here, it loops through the @xmlUserIDs and perform deletion for each id..

Comment: @Harun: My stored procedure is completed successfully. but please can u tell me that where i should have to execute this stored procedure in code?

Comment: @Divya, You should execute the code within your delete button click event. Check my "Btn_Click" event where i just fetch the selected ids to "int[] OrderIDList". You need to convert the "OrderIDList" to a comma seperated string and then execute the procedure after that (both within the same button click event).

Comment: @Harun: i did this if (grdlistWord.Rows[count].FindControl("hfCount") != null)
                    {
                        string OrderID = ((HiddenField)grdlistWord.Rows[count].FindControl("hfCount")).Value;
                        OrderIDList[index++] = Convert.ToInt32(OrderID);
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "[DeleteData]";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", OrderIDList);
                        
                    }

Comment: @Divya, so your procedure is not get called or what?

Comment: @Harun: there is no error in stored procedure showing..it is running withour any error but unable to delete any selected record.

Comment: @Divya, did you tried executing the procedure from sql server itself by passing a comma seperated string as parameter?

Comment: @Harun: sorry harun but i m not too good in coding i am working as a fresher level..so please can you tell me clearly that what i have to do?