# How can I get selected row cell value of grid view on page?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using a Grid View on my page.

I want to show the data of the selected row cell through `response.write()`, on the click event of the page button.

Comment: what coulmn type are you using in gridview like templatefield or bound field or .... better to put your gridview markup for better solutions:)

Comment: @Devjosh: column type is bound field.

Comment: you have to handle the gridview selected index changed event and in this event store the value of the cell in a variable and then fetch that value on button click the varible can be placed in partial claa of page or control whatever you are using.

Comment: @Devjosh: please can you give the complete coding.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note**::

- please set the `CommandName` of your
  button to `"selectCol"`
- Please set the `CommandName` for the
  second button , you will use to
  delete

  to`"deleteCol"`

Set the `command argument` property for your button :

**.aspx**

```
CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'
CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'
```

for the two buttons.

**.cs**

```
 protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            if (e.CommandName == "selectCol")
            {
                Response.Write(gv.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text); //consider you use bound field and the column you want to show its value is the first column.
            }

            else if(e.CommandName == "deleteCol")
             {
                 int id = int.Parse(gv.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString());//the primary key for your table.
                 Delete(id);//method which use (Delete From .... Where id = ....).
             }


            gv.DataBind();

        }

        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            string message = ee.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @just_name : thanks just_name, but it is also not deleting any selected record.

Comment: you don't tell me that u wanna to delete, u said "
I want to show the data of the selected row cell through response.write(),on the click event of the page button"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6054341/760396  please check,exactly i want to do this..

Comment: thanks.. but there is one more problem that i am not using any primary key in my table...

Comment: then how you wanna to delete by the whole row??

Comment: on the basis of selected name from gridview.

Comment: please clarify more..
The grid view have some data from table in your data base ?is this table has some primary key?

Comment: i get u , tell me first is the delete button out side the gridview or not??

Comment: i took this at the header field of the gridview.

Comment: hmmm:
you have a gridview contains set of rows,one column is (check boxes), you wanna to check set of rows and when click delete button , delete the checked rows .. is this what you wanna to do.?

Comment: good two last questions ::
1- is your delete button out side the gridview??
2- this is your method `DeleteRecord(string word)`
where you store the `word` in the gridview , which column i mean???

Comment: ans1- i am using delete button on the header field of the grid... 2-DeleteRecord(string word) is my method. i stored word on word column..

Comment: very good then please , post the the aspx (the part of the gridview) there in your link.

Answer (score 4):

Greeting Hims.

Easyest way to read value from gridview field is to write:
**your_grid_name.SelectedRow.Cell(*number_of_index*).text**

In my case that is:

**Dim employer_name As String**
**employer_name=poslodavac_grid.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text**

Just remember that first cell index is zero and that doesn't count "asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton" tag as first one ...

Answer (score 3):

Use [GridView.SelectedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx) property.

```
String cellText = this.gridView.SelectedRow.Cells[cellIndex].Text;
```

---

Refer to the following to learn about selecting a row in a `GridView` control.

[Select Command in a GridView Control in ASP.Net](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8m5f5LB6-GY)

Comment: protected void lnkbtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String cellText = grdlistWord.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString(); Response.Write(cellText.ToString()); }

Comment: when i am doing this "object reference not set to an instance of an object".error occur.

Comment: @divya: I guess you havent selected a row then. Where exactly are you getting the error ?

Comment: String cellText = grdlistWord.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString(); here i am getting error.and i had selected row through checkbox

Comment: @divya: It would be more appropriate if you used another way to select rows. Check the appended section of my answer.

Comment: @Akram Shahda : i can not select row in another way because its my task to select row through checkbox and delete selected row.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a `LINK BUTTON` in your grid view, you can use the following code in the `ROWCOMMAND` method. This code with retrieve all the values in the particular selected row.

```
 // to get the value of the link use the command argument 
 FaultId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

 // to get the other column values 

UserId = Convert.ToInt32(((GridViewRow(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer)).Cells[1].Text);  

Department = ((GridViewRow(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer)).Cells[2].Text;

ProblemType = ((GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer)).Cells[3].Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it in the RowCommand event of the gridview:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        Response.Write(row.Cells[0].Text);
        Response.Write(row.Cells[1].Text);
        ................
    }
}
```

Comment: i want the selected row on the button click event not on row command

Comment: When you click the button, RowCommand will be fired. in this event you can do whatever you want. Plus you need to set That buttom CommandName="Select"

Comment: Did you debug ? did you get into if (e.CommandName == "Select")

Comment: are you able to come into this line Response.Write(row.Cells[0].Text); ?

Comment: Can you post the html of your button here ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6054341/760396  View this..i want to exactly doing this.