# How can i send a comment in email?

Tags: asp.net, email

I have some text boxes like name,email address,phone no. and comment on my page.

I have to send the values to my email address..

How should I do this??
I am doing:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    try
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text, txtName.Text);

        SmtpClient.Host = "localhost";
        SmtpClient.Port = 25;

        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.To.Add("xyz@gmail.com");
        message.Subject = "Feedback";
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;
        message.Body = txtComment.Text;
        SmtpClient.Send(message);

        Response.Write("Email successfully sent.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Send Email Failed." + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)'
```

Comment: Can you post the solution please..

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092201-1.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SmtpClient.Host = "localhost";
    SmtpClient.Port = 25;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SmtpClient.Send(message);
```

These lines are attempting to use members of the class `SmtpClient`. However, as these members are not defined as `static`, you need to refer to your **instance** of that class, which you have called `client`.

Try

```
    client.Host = "localhost";
    client.Port = 25;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    client.Send(message);
```

Also, have a read of [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/wallen/archive/2004/11/23/268574.aspx) on the differences between class and instance members.

Finally, as SmtpClient implements IDisposable, I would change your code to wrap it in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) block, as this will ensure you are correctly cleaning up your SMTP session after you are finished with it.

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()) 
{
    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: But still email sending become failed..can you tell me? that why it is so??

Comment: @divya install stmp4dev(http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) on you local machine and test against it. It might be that your SMTP server is not setup properly

Comment: Based on your comments on the other answer, it looks like you don't actually have an SMTP server running on `localhost`. Do you understand what an SMTP server is and how it works (I'm not trying to be rude - just trying to understand your issues). I would have a look at a question like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail.

Comment: no.. not at all..(you are not rude..). but why mail sending become failed when i am doing it on localhost?? please can you tell me??

Comment: Basically, you need to be pointing your code towards an SMTP server. If there is not an SMTP server running on localhost, then the code will fail. @just_name's answer shows code using GMail's SMTP server as an alternative to running your own.

Comment: thanks @RB.. but when i am doing this using GMail's SMTP then on my mail it is taking my 2nd id in FROM.. it is not taking the id which i entered in `MAIL.FROM()`...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string sendMail(string to, string title, string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text, txtName.Text);

                if (to == "")
                    to = fromAddress.Address;
                MailAddressCollection m = new MailAddressCollection();
                m.Add(to);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.From = fromAddress;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.ReplyTo = fromAddress;
                mail.To.Add(m[0]);
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, "XXXX");//"XXXX" is the password of the sender.
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; 

                smtp.Send(mail);

                return "done";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: in line smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress, "XXXX") how can i write the password of the sender...??

Comment: i am not sending mail from one mail id to another..even i have to send some data like name and phone no and comment on a particular email id..

Comment: excuse me , i don't understand what u wanna to do..
Do u want to send an email to yourself ?

Comment: okkkk...i have a page on which user insert his name,email id,contact no and comment and then when he click on the submit button.. i want all the info filled by him. send on my email id..

Comment: how please, because according to my little knowledge ::
ASP.NET does not include a `POP3` (email receive) component. `SMTP` is for sending only.How you execute some thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

i had done this:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage();

    string name = txtName.Text.ToString();
    string contact = txtPhoneNo.Text.ToString();
    string comment = txtComment.Text.ToString();
    string checkIn = txtCheckIn.Text.ToString();
    string from = txtEmail.Text.ToString();

    mailmsg.To.Add("recipientemailid@gmail.com");
    mailmsg.From = new MailAddress(from.Trim());

    mailmsg.Subject = "Test message";

    mailmsg.Body = "This Query is submitted by user " + name.Trim() + ", "+ contact.Trim() + ", " + comment.Trim() + ", " + checkIn.Trim();
    mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("recipientemailid@Gmail.com", "password");
    client.Credentials = credentials;

    try
    {
        //try to send the mail message
        client.Send(mailmsg);
        Response.Write("sent!");
    }
    catch
    {
        //some feedback if it does not work
        Response.Write("failed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using here GMAIL SMTP Server.. can anyone tell me that how can i do this using smtp localhost..???

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
client.Host = "localhost";
client.Port = 465;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
client.Send(message);
```

Do not try to use or manage disposable emails with this because you will be  clearly exposed to spam-trappers. Your code is open and very easy to identify who is using the code and from where.